# Set Path To Image Folder In SQL Database And Display Images On ASPX Page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, image, path

Building a website with 571 houses, each house has a image associated with it. I want to set a virtual path in the database to a folder containing 571 images. There is 571 rows in the database with a few columns one of them being image I want to set the path in this column and then retrieve the image for each house on the aspx page.

I think I display the image like this

```
<asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server"
    ImageUrl='<%#Eval("path") %>'>
</asp:Image>
```

but I am not to sure how to set the path to the folder in the database.

**Database Structure**

[image]

**ASPX Page**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Format` for this as detailed below

```
ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("~/YOUR_IMAGE_FOLDER/{0}", Eval("path"))%>'
```

Just replace your ImageUrl as above.

Comment: the folder is stored on a drive not in the project

Comment: You can give virtual path or web path for that folder